# How to show all results if search is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the code below where I am trying to search by Country. On the home page there is a dropdown box to select the Country from. My problem is that it shows the results for the selected Country but if nothing is selected then there are no results.

I want it to show **ALL** Country results if there is no selection.

With this code in the mysql search if country_select was empty then there are zero results:

```
and bam.country='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country_select']))."'
```

Here is the full code:

```
$searchsql = "SELECT pp_id, appmt_id, price, max( stay_from )
                        FROM (
                        SELECT bp.pp_id, bam.appmt_id, bam.appmt_name, bp.price, bp.stay_from
                        FROM bsi_apartment_master AS bam, bsi_appmt_features AS baf, bsi_priceplan AS bp
                        WHERE bam.status=true and baf.appmt_id = bam.appmt_id".$addquery." AND baf.bedroom >=".$this->bedroom." AND baf.bathroom >=".$this->bathroom."
                        and bam.country='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country_select']))."'
                        AND bam.appmt_id NOT IN (SELECT appmt_id FROM bsi_bookings WHERE is_deleted = FALSE AND (( '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."'
                        BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( checkin_date BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )))
                        AND bam.appmt_id = bp.appmt_id
                        AND if( ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) = true, 
                        ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) AND bp.default_pp !=0, 
                        ( ".$staycount." BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) )
                        order by bp.stay_from desc
                        ) AS t1
                        GROUP BY appmt_id
                        order by price ".$this->sorting;
```

Comment: Will people ever learn about sql injection. Or performance. Or just intentional programming...

Comment: @sehe - Sorry i'm new. What would improve this coding? or can you suggest a good resource to learn from. Thanks

Comment: We all have to start somewhere :) Learn to use the mysqli extension, especially prepared statements - this looks like a good place to start: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: @Gigi thanks for that. It really bugs me about this "community" that there are easily 5 answers that don't address the basic/elementary things. It's almost like people don't want others to know the right tools...

Comment: @sehe Agreed... as much as I love StackOverflow, sometimes it's counterproductive and doesn't really help people to learn.

Comment: @Gigi - Thanks for the help and the link. Will learn from the mysqli :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$searchsql = "SELECT pp_id, appmt_id, price, max( stay_from )
                    FROM (
                    SELECT bp.pp_id, bam.appmt_id, bam.appmt_name, bp.price, bp.stay_from
                    FROM bsi_apartment_master AS bam, bsi_appmt_features AS baf, bsi_priceplan AS bp
                    WHERE bam.status=true and baf.appmt_id = bam.appmt_id".$addquery." AND baf.bedroom >=".$this->bedroom." AND baf.bathroom >=".$this->bathroom;

  if(!empty($_POST['country_select']))
  {
     $searchsql .=" and bam.country='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country_select']))."'";
   }
                    $searchsql.="AND bam.appmt_id NOT IN (SELECT appmt_id FROM bsi_bookings WHERE is_deleted = FALSE AND (( '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."'
                    BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                    OR ( DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                    OR ( checkin_date BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                    OR ( checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )))
                    AND bam.appmt_id = bp.appmt_id
                    AND if( ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) = true, 
                    ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) AND bp.default_pp !=0, 
                    ( ".$staycount." BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) )
                    order by bp.stay_from desc
                    ) AS t1
                    GROUP BY appmt_id
                    order by price ".$this->sorting;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `like` instead of `=` with `%` sign before and after searching parameter

`and bam.country like '%".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country_select']))."%'`

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the `WHERE` clause to work for either a value or if empty like:

```
AND (bam.country = $country_value OR $country_value = '')
```

This would make it so that not setting a value would return all possible values. However if you had rows with country actually blank, there would not be a way to filter for only those rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code,

```
$country_select  = $_POST['country_select'];

//To intialize search condition
$search_condition = '';

//Search condition for selected country
$search_condition .= $country_select!=""?"bam.country = '$country_select'":"";

$searchsql = "SELECT pp_id, appmt_id, price, max( stay_from )
                        FROM (
                        SELECT bp.pp_id, bam.appmt_id, bam.appmt_name, bp.price, bp.stay_from
                        FROM bsi_apartment_master AS bam, bsi_appmt_features AS baf, bsi_priceplan AS bp
                        WHERE bam.status=true and baf.appmt_id = bam.appmt_id".$addquery." AND baf.bedroom >=".$this->bedroom." AND baf.bathroom >=".$this->bathroom." $search_condition
                        AND bam.appmt_id NOT IN (SELECT appmt_id FROM bsi_bookings WHERE is_deleted = FALSE AND (( '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."'
                        BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( checkin_date BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                        OR ( checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) )))
                        AND bam.appmt_id = bp.appmt_id
                        AND if( ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) = true, 
                        ( ".$staycount." NOT BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) AND bp.default_pp !=0, 
                        ( ".$staycount." BETWEEN bp.stay_from AND bp.stay_to ) )
                        order by bp.stay_from desc
                        ) AS t1
                        GROUP BY appmt_id
                        order by price ".$this->sorting;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no country selection then the `country_select` key would be empty in `$_POST` right? so how about you keep that part of the query outside. So your huge query would look something like

```
query = "";
queryAllCountries = "SELECT FOO, BAR FROM TABLE WHERE FOO=SOMETHING"; 
if ($_POST[country_select] != null) {
    query = queryAllCountries + " AND COUNTRY = $_POST[country_select]";
} else {
    query = queryAllCountries;
}

mysql_query(query)
```

That way you append the WHERE clause **ONLY** if the `country_select` parameter is POSTED.

ps: Its been really long since i touched `PHP` and `MySQL` so the syntax might be wrong. Excuse that part. I hope you get the logic though?